# debounce function called erratically on IE 10, 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debouncing

I am using a debounce function to resize a div - it works fine except on IE 10 and 11, where it seems to be called all the time, which ends up showing scrollbars contimually off and on  and the div "flickers" . Any known solution?

Thanks.

Sorry about that - here is the function:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {

    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this,
            args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
```

// resizes the videos when the background size changes

```
var myResizingFn = debounce(function() {
    if ((myPlayer !== null) && ($('#author-pane').length === 0) && (newDimensions !== null)) {
        var tWidth = $(window).width();
        newDimensions = calculateAspectRatioFit(theWidth, theHeight, tWidth , 10000);
        s9.view.size({
            width: "100%",
            height: newDimensions.height
        });
        myPlayer.width(newDimensions.width);
        myPlayer.height(newDimensions.height);
        myPlayer.show();      
    }
}, 200);
$(window).on('resize', myResizingFn);
```

Comment: please provide code of your debounce function or library name at least

Comment: Calling all mystics...